bbcp (bare-bones file copy) in C
I have done very little systems programming, but I'm working through CS631 - Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment on my own time (I am not actually a student in the class). This is my solution for the first homework assignment: implement bbcp, an extremely basic file copy utility.
I originally wrote this solution for NetBSD, but it should also work on Linux. It passes the tests from this test script (of which I am not the author).
bbcp.c
#include <sys/stat.h>

#include <err.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <libgen.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#ifdef __linux__
#include <bsd/stdlib.h>
#else
#include <stdlib.h>
#endif
#include <unistd.h>

#ifndef BUFFSIZE
#define BUFFSIZE 32768
#endif

/*
 * Check whether the given file status refers to a directory.
 */
static bool
is_dir(struct stat *stat) {
    return S_ISDIR(stat->st_mode);
}

/*
 * Check whether the give file status refers to a regular file or FIFO.
 */
bool
is_reg_or_fifo(struct stat *stat) {
    mode_t mode = stat->st_mode;
    return S_ISREG(mode) || S_ISFIFO(mode);
}

/*
 * Check whether the given path points to a regular file or FIFO.
 */
bool
path_is_reg_or_fifo(char *path) {
    struct stat path_stat;
    if (stat(path, &path_stat) == -1) {
        err(EXIT_FAILURE, "Unable to stat destination at %s", path);
    }
    return is_reg_or_fifo(&path_stat);
}

/*
 * Replace the contents of the file at the dest_fd file descriptor with the
 * contents of the file at the source_fd file descriptor.
 */
void
replace_content(int source_fd, int dest_fd) {
    int n;
    char buf[BUFFSIZE];
    
    if (ftruncate(dest_fd, 0) == -1) {
        err(EXIT_FAILURE, "Unable to truncate destination file\n");
    }

    while ((n = read(source_fd, buf, BUFFSIZE)) > 0) {
        if (write(dest_fd, buf, n) != n) {
            err(EXIT_FAILURE, "Error while writing");
        }
    }

    if (n == -1) {
        err(EXIT_FAILURE, "Error while reading");
    }
}

/*
 * Check whether two file descriptors describe the same file.
 */
bool
is_same_file(int fd1, int fd2) {
    struct stat stat1;
    struct stat stat2;
    if (fstat(fd1, &stat1) == -1) {
        err(EXIT_FAILURE, "Unable to stat file descriptor");
    }
    if (fstat(fd2, &stat2) == -1) {
        err(EXIT_FAILURE, "Unable to stat file descriptor");
    }
    return (stat1.st_dev == stat2.st_dev) && (stat1.st_ino == stat2.st_ino);
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv) {
    setprogname(argv[0]);

    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s source target\n", getprogname());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // check that first argument is a file, not a directory
    char *source_path = argv[1];
    struct stat source_stat;
    if (!path_is_reg_or_fifo(source_path)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s is not a file\n", source_path);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    int source = open(source_path, O_RDONLY);
    if (source == -1) {
        err(EXIT_FAILURE, "Unable to open source file at %s", source_path);
    }

    // check that second argument is a valid file or directory
    char *dest_path = argv[2];
    int dest;
    struct stat dest_stat;
    
    if (stat(dest_path, &dest_stat) == -1) {
        if (errno != ENOENT) {
            err(EXIT_FAILURE, "Unable to stat destination at %s", dest_path);
        }
        dest = open(dest_path, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
        if (dest == -1) {
            err(EXIT_FAILURE, "Unable to open destination file %s", dest_path);
        }
    } else if (is_dir(&dest_stat)) {
        int dest_dir = open(dest_path, O_RDONLY);
        if (dest_dir == -1) {
            err(EXIT_FAILURE, "Unable to open destination directory %s", dest_path);
        }
        char *dest_filename = basename(source_path);
        dest = openat(dest_dir, dest_filename, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
        if (dest == -1) {
            err(EXIT_FAILURE, "Unable to open destination file %s in %s", dest_filename, dest_path);
        }
        close(dest_dir);
    } else if (is_reg_or_fifo(&dest_stat)) {
        dest = open(dest_path, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
        if (dest == -1) {
            err(EXIT_FAILURE, "Unable to open destination file %s", dest_path);
        }
    }

    if (is_same_file(source, dest)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Source and destination files cannot be the same\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    replace_content(source, dest);
    close(source);
    close(dest);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}


Makefile
CC=cc
CFLAGS=-Wall -Werror -Wextra -lbsd

bbcp: bbcp.c
    $(CC) -o bbcp bbcp.c

run: bbcp
    ./bbcp



Are you the author of the bbcp.c code that you posted in the question?

@toolic I am, yes. Sorry, I guess I phrased my question in a way that made it seem like this was just some code I found.

Thanks for confirming.  The reason I asked is because someone has voted to close the question due to authorship of the code.  Perhaps that person saw your I am not the author statement in your question, and incorrectly assumed it referred to the C code that you posted.  I'm pretty sure you simply meant that you are not the author of the linked sh script (which you do not want to be reviewed).  If that is the case, then the question should not be closed due to authorship (for anyone who arrives here via the close review queue).

That is correct. Appreciate the clarification.

What do you think you're gaining by using bsd/stdlib.h instead of stdlib.h on Linux?

@John Bollinger This program was originally written to run on NetBSD, but I wanted it to also run on Linux. getprogname and setprogname are not available on Linux without including headers from libbsd.

You didn’t ask for reviews of your Makefile, so I’ll just comment: you don’t need the bbcp recipe at all; you can define bbcp: bbcp.c without a recipe and Make will do the right thing (including applying CFLAGS).

In no particular order:

struct stat source_stat is never used.

It is unclear why the code allows copying from/to a fifo, but rejects character specials. We should be able to copy from/to /dev/ttyXXX.
Links shall not be rejected either.

Opening files in O_RDWR is questionable. The code doesn't write into the source file, and doesn't read from the destination. O_RDONLY and O_WRONLY feel more appropriate.

Destination file permissions should be based on the source file ones. If the source is executable, why the destination isn't?

is_same_file reports that it cannot stat a file descriptor, but it doesn't tell which descriptor it cannot stat.
Meanwhile, according to the code logic, by the time it is called both files have been stat'd successfully. And TOC-TOU race is still present.

Since the code allows a fifo as destination, the
  write(dest_fd, buf, n) != n

condition shall not be fatal.

Correct me if I am wrong, but opening the file for writing (not appending) automagically truncates it. There is no need to ftruncate it explicitly.



Opening a file for writing truncates the file only if the O_TRUNC option is given, without that option the existing data is overwritten.

@vnp Could you explain where the TOC-TOU race happens? My best guess is that relying on stat(dest_path, ...) leaves a window for the underlying file to change while I'm doing all my conditional logic on its result.

@nmpauls Yes, this is it.

@MartinR: Of course, the solution is to or the O_TRUNC flag in when opening and let the operations occur as a single system call, rather than ftruncate-ing after the fact and requiring two system calls.

@vnp: May I suggest that you correct the last item in your answer? Comments may be deleted at any time.

The error handling is inconsistent:
        if (dest == -1) {
            err(EXIT_FAILURE, "Unable to open destination file %s", dest_path);

    if (is_same_file(source, dest)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Source and destination files cannot be the same\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

I would probably opt for the latter, since it's more portable - but given that we're in main(), then simply return EXIT_FAILURE rather than call exit().
Note also that return EXIT_SUCCESS is redundant at the end of main().  Since C99, reaching the end of the main() function is equivalent to returning success, and so this statement can be omitted.

Your compiler could have told you about these:

The call to is_same_file() may use dest before any value is assigned.  In particular, this will happen if the destination name refers to a file that is not a regular file, directory, or fifo, or a symlink pointing directly or indirectly to one of those.

variable source_stat is unused.


Additional recommendations:

Consider whether you need additional handling for the case where the destination name designates a directory, and that directory already contains a file with the same basename as the source file.  That's not an issue when it leaves the ultimate destination referring to a regular file, but you should think about what the right behavior is if that leaves the destination referring to any other kind of file (directory, fifo, block or character special file ...).

note in particular that you call ftruncate() on the destination file, and you can only rely on that to work for regular files and POSIX shared memory objects.


if your objective is portability beyond your BSD development environment, then achieve it by using portable features, not by relying upon BSD extensions to be available in other environments.  In particular,

unconditionally include standard <stdlib.h>, not non-standard <bsd/stdlib.h>.

do not rely on non-standard library functions setprogname(), getprogname(), or err(), though you can implement your own versions if you like.

in which case you don't need to include non-standard header <err.h>



consider either declaring variables source_path and dest_path as const char * or making them point to copies of the argv strings.  The argv strings are modifiable, but modifying them (as basename() may do) is poor form.

match the types of the variables into which you receive function return values with the return types of those functions, even if you think you don't strictly need to do so for correct behavior.  In particular, read() and write() return ssize_t, not int.

as much as possible, avoid the antipattern of testing whether you can do something as a precondition for attempting it.  Prefer instead to just attempt the thing, and handle the outcome appropriately.  For example, open() first, then fstat(), rather than stat()ing first to decide how to open().  The latter has the problem that whatever state you observe in your pre-check might not still be the prevailing state when you get to performing the chosen action.

short writes are possible with write().  One does not expect them when writing to regular files, but you aren't ensuring that your destination files are regular.  As a result, if (write(dest_fd, buf, n) != n) is not a safe condition.

as @vnp also observed, the permissions of the destination file should probably be based on those of the source file.  Including in the case where the destination is a regular file that already exists.

In the case where the destination is a regular file that already exists, it would be desirable to avoid destroying it in the event that the copy ultimately fails.  The conventional way to do this is to write the copy to a temporary file first, then rename() it over the destination.

Consider what should happen when the destination is but one of multiple hardlinks to the same file.  Should the underlying file to which all the hardlinks refer be modified (as your current approach will do) or should only the path named on the bbcp command line be affected (as the temp file + rename would accomplish)?



Your feedback about compiler-caught errors revealed an error in my Makefile: I declare CFLAGS but never actually use it when compiling. I should also include the -Og flag, which enables enough optimizations to detect the unused variable.
